# Why should I put a whole onion in the turkey fryer?

Tags: deep-frying, turkey

Happy Thanksgiving! I am getting ready to fry a turkey and the [instructions](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/13824/deep-fried-turkey/) say that I should put a whole onion in with the turkey and oil.

What would be the purpose of this?

Thanks!

Comment: To make the turkey cry.

Comment: My guess would be to flavor the oil (and thus the turkey), but I'm not sure how much flavor you'll get from one onion in enough oil to fry a turkey...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having done this several times in the past - it is to make the oil flavoured. Like the comments have said that one onion doesn't seem to be enough, and frankly it isn't. I typically use 2, and remove the skins as well as score them allowing the juices to weep out a bit. Additionally, I know some people who toss a de-seeded bell pepper or two in as well, and it turns out well.

Answer (score -2):

the onion goes on the bottom so the meat doesn't touch the bottom of the pot and scorch.we used to do this before there were turkey fryers and baskets /stands.(30 years ago).
weused coat hangers wrapped around the legs to lower and raise the bird.maybe there is some flavore enhancement with the onion.

Comment: Wouldn't an onion be a particularly ineffective object to use to keep the turkey from contacting the bottom? Since it's round, it would tend to roll out of the way.

Comment: Can you provide some more info about how this is working? Doesn't the presence of a fry basket in the recipe prevent the scorching in the first place?